# absolute position prob in css

Tags: css

html code

```
<body>
       <div id="container">

               <div id="left">
                            <h2>rerererere</h2>
               </div>
               <div id="right">
                            <h2>sdadsad</h2>
               </div>
       </div>
</body>
```

CSS file

```
div#container {
position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 480px;
    height: 480px;
    border: 1px solid #0092ef; 
            /*        blue*/
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #783201;
            /*        brown*/
}
```

when I only use right div as absolute than there is no problem . But when I use absolute in both left and right div. right div becomes as small as line. I am new to css . So this might be a noob question . Why if I put two absolute div under a relative div does not work ? Please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your right `<div>` collapses because you haven't declared a fixed height for it in your CSS, that's all.

Comment: when I use height=480px It breaks the border of container. I use relative layout in container and absolute in left and right because I knew that right and left div will remain inside of container . Is there anything worng?

Comment: @Diptopol Dam ... Well, it looks like the right box extends beyond the container because you have "top" and "right" set. Just consider the dimensions of all the involved elements and adjust as necessary. You can also achieve what you're after using floats instead of absolute positioning, which removes the collapsing problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your right div has no height.

**[Here is a jsfiddle with your right div with a height](http://jsfiddle.net/bGVBU/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your right div has no height specified which is why it collapses to the line height.

Plus remove `bottom: 10px;` on the right div as this is redundant as there is a top value already specified.